# Any way to assign role to different users on the same single Wordpress page/post?

Tags: php, wordpress, roles

Hello I am working in WordPress CMS. I need to complete a project which requires different users to act on a same post/page because they will be able to access and modify only the sections of posts they can have access.

So needs some plugin or action in WordPress by which I can achieve this feature. Please help.

Thanks in Advanace :)

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Roles is a plugin that we use and it's great.

For what you need, try Capability Manager Enhanced, it is pretty intuitive once you install it.